# Customize look of the Google Maps "mapType" controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to style the look  of the mapType controls (top right "Map", "Satellite", "Hybrid") in Google maps? (using V2 of the API). Or is there a way to create your own elements and have them control the mapType??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it it possible both to change the look of the current controls and to define new ones:

look here for the functions you need: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMapType

and some examples:
create custom controls: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html#Custom_Controls
modify appearance of controls:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html#Control_Modification