# Custom GMapTypeControl buttons (Google Maps V2 API)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237022/customize-look-of-the-google-maps-maptype-controls) was already asked, but does not have a satisfying answer.

I want to change the CSS style for the map type selection buttons (which are actually DIVs that don't have a CSS class). The links in the referenced question show how to [subclass controls](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html#Custom_Controls), but the examples don't seem to work for [`GMapTypeControl`](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMapTypeControl). Tried the following

```
function CustomGMapTypeControl() {}
CustomGMapTypeControl.prototype = new GMapTypeControl()
CustomGMapTypeControl.prototype.setButtonStyle_ = function(button) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

but the `setButtonStyle_` function doesn't even get called.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

From the above code, I can say that you don't fully understand how to create a custom map control. There are 2 steps:

1. subclassing `GControl`
2. provide `initialize()` and `getDefaultPosition()` method.

Well, the `initialize` method is the place you create and style your control dom elements, and this method must return that dom element back. The `getDefaultPosition()` method indicates where this control should be placed (top-right,...), and it must return an object of type `GControlPosition`.

You must provide enough information so that when you call `map.addControl(new CustomGMapTypeControl())` so that the map object could invoke and do the right things.

NOTE: All map controls should be added to the map container which can be accessed with GMap2's `getContainer()` method.

You can play around with http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/control-custom.html when you want to create your own custom control with firebug.